# Function always returning true

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var state = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('sidebarState') ? localStorage.getItem('sidebarState') : false;

function setState() {
    if(state) {
        $('#sidebar').css('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
        state = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#sidebar').css('transform', 'translate(-100%,0)');
        state = true;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('sidebarState',state);
}

$('#sidebar_button').click(setState);

setState();

});
```

Always when I reload the page this return true, even if it is false before, so what is wrong.

Comment: The functions here aren't returning anything at all.  Perhaps you are wanting to ask why the value of the `state` variable isn't what you expect?

Comment: On refresh the state = true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem` takes two strings. So the boolean false will be coerced into the string "false", which will evaluate to true.

One fix would be

```
localStorage.setItem('sidebarState', state ? state : "");
```

since an empty string will evaluate to false.

Source:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are setting the state to true, then persisting it to localStorage with

```
localStorage.setItem('sidebarState',state);
```

When you refresh the page, state is read in from localStorage and evaluates to true.